# Fabric adds cronjob to the wrong user

Tags: python, cron, sudo, fabric

I have a  Fabric deployment scripts that along other things adds cronjobs to a specific user on the remote machine.

The fabfile first connects to the remote using the ssh config, then using `Connection.sudo(cmd)` Fabric is changing the user to the specified one and executing the command.

This works well, a part from when I try to add a cronjob, it just gets added to the regular user instead of being added the the sudoed user.

```
'prod': {
        'host': 'myhost',
        'sudo': {'user': 'special-user'},
}

def add_cronjobs(conn, cron_hash, jobs):
    if jobs:
        conn.sudo("crontab -l | grep -v '{cron_hash}' ; echo '{jobs}' | crontab -".format(cron_hash=cron_hash, jobs=jobs))

@task
def deploy(ctx):
  with Connection(host=ctx.host, config=ctx.config) as conn:
    add_cronjobs(conn, CRON_HASH, cron)
```

Other commands just work fine, but the crontab adds the job on the wrong user

Answer (score 0):

There is a known issue in fabric, more precisely in `pyinvoke` that you can follow [here](https://github.com/pyinvoke/invoke/issues/459)

The environment doesn't get picked up correctly. As a workaround I found myself invoking bash before the crontab.

```
def add_cronjobs(conn, cron_hash, jobs):
    if jobs:
      cmd = f"crontab -l | grep -v '{cron_hash}' ; echo '{jobs}' | crontab -"
      conn.sudo(f'bash -c "{cmd}"')
```